# Node JS supported versions on Heroku

Tags: node.js, version

I am trying to Push my GIT version onto heroku and i am finding the current version of node js 13.12.0 is not supported. what version is supported and how can i deploy .

It is giving deployment error and rejecting the deployment to my application in heroku

Answer (score 0):

Hello I run into the same problem and I write

```
"engines": {
  "node": "13.x.x"
}
```

The last version supported by heroku right now  is 13.11.0

You can see for yourself in
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support